# Failed to load JNI shared library "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\1.7.0_45\bin\...\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll"

Tags: java, eclipse, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install "BlackBerry_JDE_PluginFull_2.0.0_indigo" for BlackBerry development, but while i am trying open it by eclise it is poping up "Failed to load JNI shared library C:\Program Files\Java\jdk\1.7.0_45\bin...\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll", and not opening the eclipse. I have installed Java 7 Update 45(64 bit), 
My OS is 64-bit Windows 8.
Please anyone help me what is the problem?

Comment: go control panel check switch to small icons,click java and check update is available or not

Comment: This usually means you have a 32 bit Eclipse and a 64 bit Java, they need to be the same.

Answer (score 0):

[Use this link download java and install](http://c04.files.inst.avg.com/dl/patched/2014/01/01/1d1343bb7d538da28e61deed3c14ab75/JavaTMSERuntimeEnvironmentforWindowsv7update45.exe)